# phi in THREE.OrbitControl is an angle with which axis?

Tags: javascript, three.js

`phi` in the `THREE.OrbitControl` is an angle with which axis, in the code below?

```
phi += phiDelta;

// restrict phi to be between desired limits
phi = Math.max( this.minPolarAngle, Math.min( this.maxPolarAngle, phi ) );
```

I think `theta` would be an angle with y-axis in the code cause it have responsibility to perform "up" rotation.

but i not know `phi`, for sure, if it is an angle with x-axis or z-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`phi` is the polar angle -- the angle with the y-axis. The y-axis is the nominal "up" direction.

When `phi` is small, the camera is looking down from the top.

`theta` is the angle around the y-axis.

All angles are in radians.